# Jquery next() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<table class="prodtable">
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td>
     <input class="editok" value="2" />
 </td>
 <td>
  <input name="prodnumber" value="1" />
  <i></i>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this js

```
$('.prodtable').on('blur','.editok',function(){
   var neuanzahl = $(this).val();
   $(this).parent('td').text(neuanzahl);//<-- till here works fine
   $(this).parent('td').next().find('input').val(neuanzahl);//<-- from here, failure
   $(this).parent('td').next().find('i').addClass('icon-pencil'); 
});
```

the `editok` input was inserted dynamically, thats why i am setting the handler from parent table.

my problem is, on blur event, the value of the given input should be put in the next input which is inside the next `td` with name `prodnumger` and the `<i>` should get the class `icon-pencil`.

I am trying for 1 hour now, what a shame.. not a single success. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have not closed your `<td>`

Comment: And the opening element is tabe and not table

Comment: @MikeCheel no, it was just a posting typo. in original code, html is perfectly fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
$(this).parent('td').text(neuanzahl);
```

replaces everything in the TD, as that's what `text()` does, it overwrites everything, so on the next line when you do

```
$(this).parent('td').next().find('input') ...
```

there is no `this`, you just removed it with `text()`

Just chaining instead of using multiple lines will keep the reference

```
$('.prodtable').on('blur','.editok',function(){
   var neuanzahl = this.value;

   $(this).parent('td')
          .text(neuanzahl)
          .next('td')
          .find('input')
          .val(neuanzahl)
          .next('i')
          .addClass('icon-pencil'); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7748/)

Comment: i removed it only from the first td where first input was. i am trying to put in the second input which is in the next td.

Comment: ``.next()`` should go to the next td, which STILL has the input, right?

Comment: Yes it should, maybe posting an example that shows the issue would help

Comment: @doniyor When you do `.text()` it replaces *everything* in the table cell, so on the next line `$(this)` does not exist any more.

Comment: @Archer oh really? this is interesting, didnot know that

Comment: @Archer - yes, but it's confusing, he's removing everything in the *current* TD, but then call `next` which should go to the next TD, which still has the second input etc. Need to do some testing.

Comment: That's not the problem. The `next()` `td` *does* have an input, but there's no such thing as `$(this).parent()` since `this` is the *other* `input` that's just been removed from the DOM when `text()` was called - see my answer/example.

Comment: Exactly that.  Either move the `.text()` statement to the end of the function or cache the parent element like @PaulRoub has shown.

Answer (score 3):

The minute you call `$(this).parent('td').text(...)`, you've removed the `input` from its parent.  So `$(this).parent('td')` in the following calls won't match anything.

Save that `td` at the start, and use it throughout:

```
$('.prodtable').on('blur','.editok',function(){
   var neuanzahl = $(this).val();
   var td = $(this).parent('td');

   td.text(neuanzahl);
   td.next().find('input').val(neuanzahl);
   td.next().find('i').addClass('icon-pencil'); 
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/xHwdi

Comment: look, Paul. i am using ``.next()`` which should go to the next TD, which STILL has the inputfield, right?

Comment: You're using `$(this).parent('td').next()`, but `$(this).parent('td')` doesn't mean anything anymore, so `next()` doesn't do you any good. I'm doing the *same* thing here, based on the same `td`, just not trying to find it as the parent of an `input` that isn't there any more.

Comment: oooh ok. i thought, once i have the object, ``text()`` cannot remove it, but obviously it can.

Comment: Thanks Paul. it was an interesting journey now.

Answer (score 2):

[**Solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/66C3y/) is to store reference of next div in a variable.

```
$('.prodtable').on('blur', '.editok', function () {
    var td =  $(this).parent('td'); 
    var next =  $(this).parent('td').next(); //Store reference of next div in a variable
    var neuanzahl = $(this).val();
    td.text(neuanzahl); 
    next.find('input').val(neuanzahl);
    next.find('i').addClass('icon-pencil');
});
```

Problem with your code is that when `$(this).parent('td').text(neuanzahl)` reference to `this` is lost as you have replaced the content to `td`.

Comment: so that I have something to work further even after ``text()``ing right?

Comment: Yes, If you want to perform further operation.

Answer (score -2):

Your table opening tag is not spelled correctly that is likely why you are having difficulties.